# C# Private Setter with Logic

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Crystal_Message
{
    class Person
    {
        private string firstName="";
        private string lastName= "";
        private string phone="";


        public Person(string firstName, string lastName, string phone)
        {
            this.FirstName = firstName;
            this.LastName = lastName;
            this.PhoneNumber = phone;


        }

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return firstName; }

            set
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.firstName)){

                    throw new ArgumentNullException("Must Include First Name");
                }

                this.firstName = value;
            }

        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get { return lastName; }

            set
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastName)){

                    throw new ArgumentNullException("Must Include Last Name");
                }

                this.lastName = value;
            }

        }

        public string PhoneNumber
        {
            get { return phone; }

            set
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(phone)){

                    throw new ArgumentNullException("Must Include Phone Number");
                }

                this.phone = value;
            }

        }


        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "First Name: " + this.FirstName + " " + " Last Name: " + this.LastName + " Phone Number: " + this.PhoneNumber;
        }


    }
}
```

I have a simple person class that takes the first name, last name and email. It works for me, and it won't be sub classed.  I'm building a small application, and the person class is suitable.

My only issue is, how would I implement a **private** setter with internal logic, to make sure the value isn't null or empty?

Comment: Adding private in front of set ie `private set....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make only the setter private. Also, you have a problem in that this:

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastName)
```

will read the *existing* property value. You should inspect the newly-supplied `value` instead:

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)
```

Final code:

```
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }

        private set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Must Include Last Name");
            }

            lastName = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ah, I was about to post about this here. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use private modifier for your property setter:

```
public string FirstName
{
    get { return firstName; }

    private set
    {
        // Here you must check if value is not null or empty, not the field
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)){
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Must Include First Name");
        }
        this.firstName = value;
    }
}
```

In this case the setter of a property will only be accessible from the same class.

Comment: Many thanks! My only issue is, The argumentnullexception displays even though the first name has a value, do you know why?

Comment: @Nexusfactor I updated the answer. You need to check the value, not the field

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways:

First, you could just get rid of the `set` and your class can operate on the underlying value:

```
public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
    }
}

// Then in your code:
this.firstName = "whatever"; // the local variable
```

Or you can scope the setter as `private`:

```
public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }

        private set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.firstName)){

                throw new ArgumentNullException("Must Include First Name");
            }

            this.firstName = value;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Many thanks! My only issue is, The argumentnullexception displays even though the first name has a value, do you know why?

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that. In the setter you're checking `this.firstName` for null/whitespace, but you should be checking `value` instead.

Comment: Just to clarify, in the string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.firstName) it should be string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value), correct?

Comment: yes: `if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) {...` - `value` is the incoming value passed to the setter.